# Adding two Plots (Bar and Scatter) using coreplot in iOS w.r.t multiple Y axis

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I using coreplot , and I want to plot two plots ,1) Bar Plot w.r.t Y1 axis 2) Scatter Plot w.r.t Y2 axis, as shown in the below figure with different set of values.

[image]

I managed to create the Y2 axis on the right side by the code below,by referring to the code in CorePlotTestApp example.

```
CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[(CPTXYAxis *)[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    //y2.labelingPolicy            = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"10");
    y2.minorTicksPerInterval       = 1;
    y2.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 2;
    y2.labelOffset             = -20.0f; 
    y2.titleOffset                     = -23.0f;
    y2.coordinate              = CPTCoordinateY;
    y2.plotSpace               = plotSpaceRightYaxis;
    y2.axisLineStyle               = lineStyle;
    y2.majorTickLineStyle          = lineStyle;
    y2.minorTickLineStyle          = lineStyle;
    //y2.visibleRange              = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(20)];
    y2.title              = @"Y2Title";
    y2.labelTextStyle                 = textStyle;
    y2.titleLocation          = CPTDecimalFromInteger(4);

    y2.axisConstraints            = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];       


    graph.axisSet.axes   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y,y2,nil];
```

I can plot the bar graph and scatter plot but with respect to only Y1 axis on left but I want to plot it with respect to Y2 axis so how should I proceed with this,please help me out, waiting for your reply.

Regards
Ranjit.

Comment: Hello friends ,I found out the answer for this question,we need to create an instance of CPTPlotSpace and assign the Y2 axis plot space to this  and also add this plotspace to graph.if any doubts feel free to ask

Comment: It would be good if you can post your comment as answer for future reference

Comment: Thanku for posting code as well. This is exactly what u was searching for :)

Comment: Hi Ranjit, could you tell please how you've added grid lines for X axis for each 4 portions of data? I am willing to achieve the same result, but till no success. Any comment will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @SergeyN., this is just a sample image, I did not code that gridLines

Comment: Hi @Ranjit, oh, I hoped it was coded. But thank you for your response.
I can suppose that this can be done with majorGridlineStyle, but still thinking on how to do that for not every major tick.